# NSFetchedresultController sectionNameKeyPath based on range between current location and other location

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an `entity` with objects in it. These objects have `Latitude` and `longitude`. I also added an `transient attribute` `range` where I calculate the range. Please look at the class below:

```
@implementation Relation

@dynamic firstLetter;
@dynamic rel_address;
@dynamic rel_balanceTotal;
@dynamic rel_bank_country_code;
@dynamic rel_bank_number;
@dynamic rel_city;
@dynamic rel_city_id;
@dynamic rel_code;
@dynamic rel_country;
@dynamic rel_country_code;
@dynamic rel_customerProspect;
@dynamic rel_email;
@dynamic rel_expired_total;
@dynamic rel_fax;
@dynamic rel_gsm;
@dynamic rel_name;
@dynamic rel_phone;
@dynamic rel_turnovertotal;
@dynamic rel_vat_country_code;
@dynamic rel_vat_number;
@dynamic rel_website;
@dynamic rel_zipcode;
@dynamic rel_longitude;
@dynamic rel_latitude;
@dynamic range;

-(NSNumber *)range{
    NSNumber *rangeFromCurrentLocation;

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"range"];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[self.rel_latitude floatValue] longitude:[self.rel_longitude floatValue]];
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:appDelegate.latitude longitude:appDelegate.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [location2 distanceFromLocation:location];  //      distance is expressed in meters

    CLLocationDistance kilometers = distance / 1000.0;

    float floatrange = ceil(kilometers / 5.0) * 5;
    rangeFromCurrentLocation = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatrange];

    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"range"];
    NSLog(@"RANGE IS %@",rangeFromCurrentLocation);

    return rangeFromCurrentLocation;
}
```

What I want to do is build up a list with sections of 5km, 10km, 15km, ....
At startup I load only the relations in that are in a radius of 5km. I do this like this.

```
_searchDistance = 2.50;
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

float minLat = appDelegate.latitude - (_searchDistance / 69);
float maxLat = appDelegate.latitude + (_searchDistance / 69);
float minLon = appDelegate.longitude - _searchDistance / fabs(cos(appDelegate.longitude / 180.0 * M_PI)*69);
float maxLon = appDelegate.longitude + _searchDistance / fabs(cos(appDelegate.longitude / 180.0 * M_PI)*69);

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Relation" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rel_latitude <= %f AND rel_latitude >= %f AND rel_longitude <= %f AND rel_longitude >= %f", maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"rel_name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort,nil]];
```

This is working correctly and I only get the objects inside a `radius of 5km`. At the bottom of my tableView I have a `load more button` where I change the `_searchDistance` ( I add another 5km)

For building up my list I use this `NSFetchedresultController`:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"range"
                                                   cacheName:nil];
```

**Problem**

When the view loads every thing is oké. But when I hit load more, I get an empty list and get this error in my log

```
CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) The fetched object at index 6 has an out of order section name '10. Objects must be sorted by section name'
2014-04-23 12:01:27.673 Adsolut[2097:60b] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x167630f0 {reason=The fetched object at index 6 has an out of order section name '10. Objects must be sorted by section name'}, {
    reason = "The fetched object at index 6 has an out of order section name '10. Objects must be sorted by section name'";
```

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all objects are first sorted according to the first sort descriptor,
and then grouped into sections according to the `sectionNameKeyPath`. 
The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states about this parameter:

> If this key path is not the same as that specified by the first sort
>   descriptor in fetchRequest, they must generate the same relative
>   orderings.

That means that you have to use a first sort descriptor that sorts all objects
according to their distance to the current location. Unfortunately, this sort descriptor
can only use a *persistent* attribute. But there is (as far as I know) no way around this
restriction if you use a fetched results controller.

Comment: What do you suggest I do then ?

Comment: @StefGeelen: You could compute the distance and store it as a (permanent) attribute in the entity. When the current location changes then you have to re-compute it. - Or do not use a FRC and implement your own code to group the objects into sections. - Both solutions are not 100% satisfying, but that are the restrictions of an FRC.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Martin R.

The method I use is to build logic into my `NSFetchedResultsController`, such that, if it exists, the first sort descriptor is always the `section`, with other sort descriptors added into the sort descriptor array as second, third, fourth, etc.

In this way you are protecting your FRC against the crash you are currently experiencing.

**UPDATE...**

Further to discussion, I have included my somewhat edited method to prepare a FRC that includes protection against the crash you are experiencing. As noted, this may not work with a transient attribute.

This code has the following public properties set before the method is fired.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *entity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sectionIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sortAttributePrimary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sortAttributeSecondary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sortAttributeTertiary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sortAttributeQuaternary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPredicate *requestPredicate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cacheName;
```

Each of these properties is set by the entity object that calls the FRC. By default set `sortAttributePrimary = nil` when a value exists for `sectionIdentifier`.

Also note that `(BOOL)userSettingListsSortAscending` is an `NSUserDefault` that is also determined in the first part of this method, however has been removed to try to keep the code to a reasonable size.

```
- (void)configureFetch {
    if (self.managedObjectContext) {

        ...< other code including preparation of NSPredicate>...

        //  Prepare and set Sort Descriptors
        NSArray *requestSortDescriptors = nil;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorPrimary = nil;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorSecondary = nil;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorTertiary = nil;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorQuaternary = nil;

        if (self.sortAttributePrimary != nil) {
            sortDescriptorPrimary = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:self.sortAttributePrimary ascending:userSettingListsSortAscending selector:@selector(compare:)];
        } else if (self.sortAttributePrimary == nil) {
            sortDescriptorPrimary = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:self.sectionIdentifier ascending:userSettingListsSortAscending];
        }

        if (self.sortAttributeSecondary != nil) {
            sortDescriptorSecondary = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:self.sortAttributeSecondary ascending:userSettingListsSortAscending selector:@selector(compare:)];
        }

        if (self.sortAttributeTertiary != nil) {
            sortDescriptorTertiary = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:self.sortAttributeTertiary ascending:userSettingListsSortAscending selector:@selector(compare:)];
        }

        if (self.sortAttributeQuaternary != nil) {
            sortDescriptorQuaternary = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:self.sortAttributeQuaternary ascending:userSettingListsSortAscending selector:@selector(compare:)];
        }

        if (sortDescriptorPrimary != nil) {
            if (sortDescriptorSecondary != nil) {
                if (sortDescriptorTertiary != nil) {
                    if (sortDescriptorQuaternary != nil) {
                        requestSortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptorPrimary, sortDescriptorSecondary, sortDescriptorTertiary, sortDescriptorQuaternary, nil];
                    } else if (sortDescriptorQuaternary == nil) {
                        requestSortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptorPrimary, sortDescriptorSecondary, sortDescriptorTertiary, nil];
                    }
                } else if (sortDescriptorTertiary == nil) {
                    requestSortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptorPrimary, sortDescriptorSecondary, nil];
                }
            } else if (sortDescriptorSecondary == nil) {
                requestSortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptorPrimary, nil];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - sortDescriptors are: %@_", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), requestSortDescriptors);
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:requestSortDescriptors];

        //  Set fetchedResultsController
        if (self.sectionIdentifier == nil || [self.sectionIdentifier isEqualToString:@""]) {
            self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:self.cacheName];
        } else {
            self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:self.sectionIdentifier cacheName:self.cacheName];
        }
        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    } else {
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }
}
```

Finally it is worth noting as a subtext that I sort using `compare:` instead of `localizedCaseInsentiveCompare:`, because at times one of my sort descriptors is an `NSDate`.

Comment: There are many examples where the section key is not identical to the first sort descriptor. In this question, the first sort descriptor could be the distance to the current location and the section key would be the distance rounded to multiples of 5 (km). - Another example is when the objects are sorted by a date, and the section key is just year-month-day.

Comment: @MartinR what do you suggest I can do?

Comment: Is it worthwhile posting my code as to how I do this? I admit I do not use a transient attribute as my section, however it may provide some clue to a solution.